# Python3: purge exception chain?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, urwid

I'm trying to raise an exception within an `except:` block but the interpreter tries to be helpful and prints stack traces 'by force'. Is it possible to avoid this?

A little bit of background information: 
I'm toying with urwid, a [TUI library](http://excess.org/urwid/) for python. The user interface is started by calling `urwid.MainLoop.run()` and ended by *raising* `urwid.ExitMainLoop()`. So far this works fine but what happens when another exception is raised? E.g. when I'm catching `KeyboardInterrupt` (the urwid MainLoop does not), I do some cleanup and want to end the user interface - by raising the appropriate exception. But this results in a screen full of stack traces.

Some little research showed python3 remembers chained exceptions and one can explicitly raise an exception with a 'cause': `raise B() from A()`. I learned a few ways to change or append data regarding the raised exceptions but I found no way to 'disable' this feature. I'd like to avoid the printing of stack traces and lines like `The above exception was the direct cause of...` and just raise the interface-ending exception within an `except:` block like I would outside of one.

Is this possible or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

**Edit**:
Here's an example resembling my current architecture, resulting in the same problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

class Exit_Main_Loop(Exception):
    pass

# UI main loop
def main_loop():
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except Exit_Main_Loop as e:
        print('Exit_Main_Loop')
        # do some UI-related clean up

# my main script
try:
    main_loop()
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    # do some clean up
    raise Exit_Main_Loop()      # signal the UI to terminate
```

Unfortunately I can't change `main_loop` to except `KeyboardInterrupt` as well. Is there a pattern to solve this?

Comment: Do you want no stack trace at all, or do you want just the outermost exception's stack trace, or just the innermost exception's stack trace?

Comment: If you don't want _any_ stack trace, just wrap your whole "main" code in a `try:`/`except Exception as e:` and then handle the exception however you want (e.g., `print(repr(e)); sys.exit(1)`).

Comment: I'd like to have nothing indicating an exception occurred (for the user) - no stack trace or other text output (except things I print myself, of course). I mean, I catched the exception and did what I had to do - there's no stack trace needed anymore (I'd print it myself if I wanted to read it). Similarly, urwid.MainLoop catches the Exit exception silent, too. I see no reason why just because there are two exceptions in a row (both catched properly) should result in an output resembling an uncatched exception.

Comment: I still don't understand your issue. Can you give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem (preferably one that doesn't use `urwid` or any other event loop at all)?

Comment: I added a small example, resembling my 'design' and the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't quite understand your explanation, but from the code:

```
try:
    main_loop()
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    print('KeyboardInterrupt')
    # do some clean up
    raise Exit_Main_Loop()      # signal the UI to terminate
```

There is no way that `main_loop` could ever see the `Exit_Main_Loop()` exception. By the time you get to the `KeyboardInterrupt` handle, `main_loop` is guaranteed to have already finished (in this case, because of an unhandled `KeyboardInterrupt`), so its exception handler is no longer active.

So, what happens is that you raise a new exception that nobody catches. And when an exception gets to the top of your code without being handled, Python handles it automatically by printing a traceback and quitting.

If you want to convert one type of exception into another so `main_loop` can handle it, you have to do that somewhere *inside* the `try` block.

You say:

> Unfortunately I can't change main_loop to except KeyboardInterrupt as well.

If that's true, there's no real answer to your problem… but I'm not sure there's a problem in the first place, other than the one you created. Just remove the `Exit_Main_Loop()` from your code, and isn't it already doing what you wanted? If you're just trying to prevent Python from printing a traceback and exiting, this will take care of it for you.

---

If there really *is* a problem—e.g., the `main_loop` code has some cleanup code that you need to get executed no matter what, and it's not getting executed because it doesn't handle `KeyboardInterrupt`—there are two ways you could work around this.

---

First, as the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#general-rules) docs explain:

> The `signal.signal()` function allows to define custom handlers to be executed when a signal is received. A small number of default handlers are installed: … `SIGINT` is translated into a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

So, all you have to do is replace the default handler with a different one:

```
def handle_sigint(signum, frame):
    raise ExitMainLoop()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)
```

Just do this before you start `main_loop`, and you should be fine. Keep in mind that there are some limitations with threaded programs, and with Windows, but if none of those limitations apply, you're golden; a ctrl-C will trigger an `ExitMainLoop` exception instead of a `KeyboardInterrupt`, so the main loop will handle it. (You may want to also add an `except ExitMainLoop:` block in your wrapper code, in case there's an exception *outside of* `main_loop`. However, you could easily write a `contextmanager` that sets and restores the signal around the call to `main_loop`, so there isn't any outside code that could possibly raise it.)

---

Alternatively, even if you can't edit the `main_loop` source code, you can always monkeypatch it at runtime. Without knowing what the code looks like, it's impossible to explain exactly how to do this, but there's almost always a way to do it.

Comment: In reality `main_loop()` is an external (ui) library that needs to terminate properly and this is done by raising (the also external) `Exit_Main_Loop`. I see your point, there's no way for it to work like it currently is but I don't know how to model it in a better (working/correct) way.

Comment: So is there any actual problem, with the main loop not doing some proper shutdown that you need it to do because it doesn't handle `KeyboardInterrupt`? If so, there are two ways you can work around the problem, but they're both going to be at least a little ugly. Let me edit the answer to explain.

Comment: Well, it performs a proper cleanup even in case of a `KeyboardInterrupt` (except for a printed stack trace) but in this case I need to do some clean up, too (prior to shutting down the UI). My initial answer was a bit... messy, mainly because I had a wrong understanding of the problem itself, sorry. Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm going with the signal handler.